# list all child categories that apply to current post even if those cats are empty?

Tags: categories, hierarchical

list all child categories that apply to current post even if those cats are empty?
everything I tried just shows "post not found" -

Have alphabetical listing and trying to create

A B C D  hyperlinked listing

A - All categories that child of A
B - All categories that child of B etc

Answer (score 1):

[get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

[get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

[get_category_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)

```
<?php 
echo '<ul>';
foreach(get_the_category() as $cat) { 
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->term_id).'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';
    $sub_cats = get_categories('parent='.$cat->term_id.'&hide_empty=0');
    if($sub_cats) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($sub_cats as $sub_cat) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($sub_cat->term_id).'">'.$sub_cat->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

edit:
for a list of sub categories in a category archive, try this code:

```
<?php  
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$cat_list = wp_list_categories('child_of='.$cat.'&hide_empty=0&title_li=&echo=0');
    if($cat_list) {
    echo 'Sub-category List <ul>';
    echo $cat_list;
    echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
```

[wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: this works but only if the category isnt empty -  I was looking for a solution that would still pull child categories even if the current category is empty

Comment: 'list all child categories that apply to current post ' - can you explain, how can a current category of a post be empty? the suggested code will show empty sub categories.

Comment: apologies this is my mistake - essentially I need to create a category nav that shows the child and grandchild categories of the current category, whether the current category has posts assigned or not

Comment: edited the answer to include some code for the category archive template.